# How to get programmatically JOptionPane message content

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities

My application is integrated with 3rd party standalone application which will open JOptionPane dialog boxes in separate thread and I am running the thread to close all the opened dialog boxes.So before closing I need to get the message written on dialog box.

My sample main program with which I am trying to achieve:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        Window[] possibleWindow = Window.getWindows();
        if (possibleWindow != null && possibleWindow.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("Found " + possibleWindow.length + "Window(s) " + possibleWindow[0].getClass().getSuperclass());
            for (int i = possibleWindow.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                try {
                    Window window = possibleWindow[i];
                    //here where I need to get the dialog box message before closing it.
                    window.dispose();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test !!!!");
}
```

Comment: are you certain that all references in the possibleWindow array will be instances of JOptionPane?  If so, would it make more sense in your application to either Extend (by direct extension or encapsulation) JOptionPane to create a new class that would register the contents of the Pane when it is created?  That way you would not be trying to play clean up at the end.

Comment: I just checked, JOptionPane is not a subclass of Window.  So I don't see how it can show up in the array of  possible Window.  But if you can get a reference to an existing JOptionPane by some other method, then you can just call JOptionPane.getMessage() to get the message object.

Comment: My application is integrated with 3rd party swing standalone application and I am no were creating JOptionPane objects to show message dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you crate JOptionPane objects and give them a message; and later on, you want to know the message you gave to them?

If so, a simple solution would be to create a central map, like `Map<JOptionPane, String>`. Each time you create a new JOptionPane, you remember it (and its message); and upon cleanup; you simply fetch the messages for those JOptionPane objects that are still up.

Comment: My application is integrated with 3rd party swing standalone application and I am no were creating JOptionPane objects to show message dialogs

Answer (score 0):

You need recursively all components of window.
This solution will work in your case :

```
public static String getMess(Container w){              
    for (Component component : w.getComponents()) {
        if (component instanceof JLabel) {
            return ((JLabel) component).getText();
        }
        else if (component instanceof JTextField){
            return ((JTextField) component).getText();
        }
        else if (component instanceof Container){
            String s = getMess((Container) component);
            if (!s.isEmpty()){
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I tried you solution, didn't work for me. I had tried with my sample main method program.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me :

```
   if (window instanceof JDialog) {
        System.out.println("text : " + ((JOptionPane)((JDialog) window).getContentPane().getComponents()[0]).getMessage());
    }
```